# Extracting the Numbers from the nested List

Tags: python, list

Am new to python
I have a nested list around here,

```
[['Elevation 3,000 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is0 '], ['Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is5 '], ['Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is10 ']]
```

From the above nested list i want basically number from the list.

**My final list should look like,**

```
[['3000'], ['0'], ['3000','4500'], ['5'], ['4500' , '5400'], ['10']]
```

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Loop and regular expressions...

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please don't accept blatantly incorrect solutions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* coding-related issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Includes too much for, but works. (Assumes there is just 1 item in every list in "lists". It can be fixed.)

```
lists = [['Elevation 3,000 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is0 '], ['Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is5 '], ['Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is10 ']]
result = []
for list in lists:
    numbers = []
    str = list[0].replace(",", "").replace(".", "")
    for word in str.split():    #separate from space
        number = ""
        for char in word:
            if char.isdigit():
                number += char 
        if number:      
            numbers.append(number)  
    result.append(numbers)

print (result)
```

Output:

```
[['3000'], ['0'], ['3000', '4500'], ['5'], ['4500', '5400'], ['10']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write any code so I won't give you a complete solution.

```
>>> data = [['Elevation 3,000 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is0 '], ['Elevation > 3,000 and 4,500 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is5 '], ['Elevation > 4,500 and 5,400 feet'], [' Ground Snow Load is10 ']]
>>> import re
>>> [re.findall('\d+',l[0]) for l in data]
[['3', '000'], ['0'], ['3', '000', '4', '500'], ['5'], ['4', '500', '5', '400'], ['10']]
```

Now you just need to remove the `,`s first, or accept a mix of digits and `,` in  the regex.

Comment: Oh never mind, I realised you left that out on purpose.

Comment: @Eric Duminil Even i too tried with the same regex, That made me ask the question.